# Can't call my API with .AddOpenIdConnect() Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

In blazor asp.net core 6.0 hosted I'm trying to authorize with an external Identity Provider with OpenId-connect. This is the configuration which I've tried:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
            options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"];
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        });
```

I generate Tokens with the authflow PKCE over my Identity provider. When I send a request on postman to my API, the request can't be send.

I've also tried authorizing with the `.AddJwtbearer()` configuration. In that case I would get an unauthorized 403 code as response, because of the missing selfsigning-key. But as I have mentioned I was using PKCE authflow to generate a token so I don't have a selfsigning-key.

I am grateful for every help!

Comment: The timeout probably isn't caused by the authorize tag. Try directly setting the OIDC options for PKCE and others in code: options.UsePkce = true; options.SignInScheme="Cookies"; options.Scope.Add(options.ClientId);

Comment: @GH DevOps Thanks for the response. I wasn't thinking it was caused by the Authorize tag, sorry for the poor wording. I have no Idea where the problem is. I tried it with the addidtional options but on postman but it still couldn't send the request.

Comment: Capture the traffic with something like Fiddler and see if the response gives you more info than your browser or postman.